# JavaScript FileReader how to read different encoding files

Tags: javascript, filereader

In my React project, when the user uploads `UTF-8` encoding file, I can handle it by:

```
fileReader.readAsText(inputFile, 'UTF-8');
```

But if the user uploads `GB2312` encoding file, then this file reader cannot read the text correctly.

Is there a way that I can detect what encoding the file is using so that I can pass the correct encoding format to the file reader?

Comment: Best approach: have the user choose the encoding, or just tell them to convert to utf-8 before uploading. There is no 100% reliable method for [charset detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charset_detection), it's always a heuristic.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file